# Makefile: no rule to make target '%.o', needed by '%'. Stop

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I got the following error:

`make: *** No rule to make target cardemo.o, needed by cardemo.exe.  Stop`

Trying to make this makefile

```
#Makefile for djgpp

#ALLEG  =-lalleg
CC  =gcc

OBJECTS = cardemo.o

all:    cardemo.exe


#executables

cardemo.exe:$(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) $(ALLEG) -o $@ 


clean:
    del *.o
    del cardemo.exe
```

This is my first time creating a makefile with the help of Tutorials and Templates from Google just some days ago so excuse me if you find other mistakes thanks.

Comment: Do you have a file called *cardemo.c* in the same directory as the Makefile? Or better: please share the name of your source file(s).

Comment: CristiFati Yes i do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [[GNU]:  Catalogue of Built-In Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html):

> **Compiling C programs**
>
> *n.o* is made automatically from *n.c* with a recipe of the form `$(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c`.

Example:

- *cardemo.c*:

  ```c
  int main()
  {
      return 0;
  }
  ```
- *Makefile*:

  ```make
  #Makefile for djgpp

  #ALLEG = -lalleg
  #CC = gcc

  OBJECTS = cardemo.o

  all: cardemo.exe

  #executables

  cardemo.exe: $(OBJECTS)
      $(CC) $(OBJECTS) $(ALLEG) -o $@

  clean:
      del *.o
      del cardemo.exe
  ```

**Output**:

> ```sh
> (qaic-env) [cfati@cfati-5510-0:/mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q075071635]> ~/sopr.sh
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [064bit prompt]> ls
> Makefile  cardemo.c
> [064bit prompt]> make
> cc    -c -o cardemo.o cardemo.c
> cc cardemo.o  -o cardemo.exe
> [064bit prompt]> ls
> Makefile  cardemo.c  cardemo.exe  cardemo.o
> ```

Everything went fine, so the only logical conclusion one could draw is that you don't have a file called *cardemo.c* in the same directory.
If you modify *OBJECTS* related line (to `OBJECTS = cardemo_notexist.o`), you will get the same error.

To get past this, **either**:

1. Rename the source file from whatever name has now (could it be *car**d**demo.c* ?) to *cardemo.c*

   **Note**: as @Mopower mentioned in a comment, original was ***C**ardemo.c*
2. Rename the object name so it has the source file stem name: `OBJECTS = sourcefile_name.o`
3. If renaming any of the 2 items above is not an option (or maybe *cardemo.c* is located in a different directory), add a compilation rule that will build *cardemo.o* from *sourcefile_name.c*:

   > ```make
   > cardemo.o: sourcefile_name.c
   >     $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
   > ```

Comment: I renamed the sourcefile it was Cardemo.c instead of cardemo.c Thanks i no longer have the error about the rule.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have putted `$(OBJECTS)` in the dependencies spot, which means makefile will need to make that file first (if it doesn't exist), so you should add a rule to make objs from c file like this:

```
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -o $@ -c $<
```

`$@` means the target name, `$<` means the first dependency (You can also use `$^` here, `$^` means all the dependencied).

Comment: You don't need to add this rule.  Make has a built-in rule that knows how to do this, as long as you don't have any special requirements.